# Consult on React-Redux action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, frontend

I am new and is learning `react-redux`. currently tweaking a template. Have been scratching my head for a very long time on it.

I am facing issue in comprehending the code and will like to consult the community here on

```
export default (state = { products: [],detail_products: [] }, action) => {
if(action.type === "ACTUAL_PRODUCTS")
{
    return { ...state,
        products: action.products };
```

Can any experts explain to me what the code below is running. I understand basic `redux` but is having issue reading the code "product(ProductsList)". `product` isn't a function isn't it?

```html
import ProductsList from '../api/product.json';

export const  fetchProducts = (product, times) => (
     setTimeout(() => product(ProductsList), times || 150)
)

export const ProductsData = () => dispatch => {
    dispatch({type: "GET_PRODUCTS_VALUE"});

    let a = products => {dispatch({ type: "ACTUAL_PRODUCTS", products });
    return products;
}
    fetchProducts(a)
}
```

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: fetchProducts is called passing 'a' variable. a variable is a function that receives a list of products and dispatches an action with type 'ACTUAL_PRODUCTS' and products. This action is the one that reaches the reducer that updates the state.

Comment: hey thanks alot. that is my understanding too. but can you explain to me product(ProductsList)?

Comment: product is indeed a function. you are invoking it and passing productList as an argument. this function is declared here: 'let a = products => {dispatch({ type: "ACTUAL_PRODUCTS", products });', as you can see this function dispatches an action using the productList.

Comment: just to confirm productList is actually passed into function "a" as products. thank you so much

Comment: Exactly :).........